# How to add/use javascript code in Django textfield in the condition that safe filter is used?

Tags: javascript, python, django, textfield, echarts

How to add/use javascript code in Django textfield in the condition that safe filter is used? Will django textfield filter out all the `<script></script>`?

I want to add/use some interactive charts plugin in my blog post, which uses javascript API, namely I need to use`<script>...</script>`in my blog post, but all the content of my blog post is in the `TextField()` of Django models. The chart **can not** be shown in the post of the frontend, but it can be shown outside the post/TextField() in the web page if I put the js code outside the `{{post.body|safe}}`. `body = models.TextField()`. What's reason for that? Please help me.

Comment: you are unclear, can you add some code if you tried anything?

Comment: _please_ don't post images.

Comment: I have added some pictures, please check it again, thanks very much

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers    Why? I think you don't need to copy the code

Comment: I added some more descriptions, hope it will help.

Comment: @Oak https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Thanks, I have removed the screenshots and added more details of the problem. please check it.